# Delete duplicates from table with priority order

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have table with example data:

```
+----+----------------------------+---------------------------------+----------------------------------+--------+----------+-----------+---------+-----+
| id |            url             |           description           |         description_hash         |  city  | latitude | longitude | service | sid |
+----+----------------------------+---------------------------------+----------------------------------+--------+----------+-----------+---------+-----+
|  1 | www.website.com/sdadsd12d1 | Some description here version 1 | 94b35433ecd64545db9c9129b877ea49 | Paris  | 48.85670 | 2.35146   | website |   1 |
|  2 | www.page.com/gfdg3df2f2    | Some description here version 1 | 94b35433ecd64545db9c9129b877ea49 | Paris  | 48.85670 | 2.35146   | page    |   2 |
|  3 | www.site.com/sdjbhsjhd17   | Some description here version 1 | 94b35433ecd64545db9c9129b877ea49 | Paris  | 48.85670 | 2.35146   | site    |   3 |
|  4 | www.site.com/sdsdadqwd12   | Some description here version 1 | 94b35433ecd64545db9c9129b877ea49 | Berlin | 52.51704 | 13.38886  | site    |   3 |
|  5 | www.page.com/dgdg2wg3      | Some description here version 2 | 764ed2b4f0d28e45332816c7beedb706 | Berlin | 52.51704 | 13.38886  | page    |   2 |
|  6 | www.webpage.com/8f8fj2h    | Some description here version 2 | 764ed2b4f0d28e45332816c7beedb706 | Berlin | 52.51704 | 13.38886  | webpage |   4 |
+----+----------------------------+---------------------------------+----------------------------------+--------+----------+-----------+---------+-----+
```

My task is delete duplicates rows. I want unique combinations of description_hash, service and latitude (city). Until today, I have been using the following query:

```
    update my_table_data
    set description_hash = md5(description::text)
    where description_hash is null;

    DROP VIEW temp_view_duplicates;
    CREATE VIEW temp_view_duplicates AS WITH A   
    AS  (
       SELECT Distinct
              description_hash
         ,    service
       FROM  my_table_data
    )
    ,   B  
    AS  (
        SELECT description_hash
        FROM   A
        GROUP BY
               description_hash
        HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
    ), C
    AS (
    SELECT  A.description_hash,
            A.service
    FROM    A
        JOIN B
            ON A.description_hash = B.description_hash
            order by description_hash
    ), D AS
    (
    select distinct latitude, description_hash, service
    from my_table_data
    where description_hash in (SELECT description_hash FROM C)
    order by description_hash
    ), E AS
    (SELECT description_hash, latitude
    FROM   D
    GROUP BY
           description_hash, latitude
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1)
      SELECT min(ctid) as min_ctid, description_hash, latitude
    FROM   my_table_data
        WHERE description_hash in (SELECT description_hash FROM E)
        group by description_hash, latitude
        order by description_hash;
                                    
    DELETE FROM my_table_data a USING (
      SELECT min_ctid, description_hash, latitude
        FROM  temp_view_duplicates
      ) b
      WHERE a.description_hash = b.description_hash AND a.latitude = b.latitude
      AND a.ctid <> b.min_ctid;
```

The result is good, but query deletes rows randomly, based on different ctid's.
Example result:

```
+----+----------------------------+---------------------------------+----------------------------------+--------+----------+-----------+---------+-----+
| id |            url             |           description           |         description_hash         |  city  | latitude | longitude | service | sid |
+----+----------------------------+---------------------------------+----------------------------------+--------+----------+-----------+---------+-----+
|  1 | www.website.com/sdadsd12d1 | Some description here version 1 | 94b35433ecd64545db9c9129b877ea49 | Paris  | 48.85670 | 2.35146   | website |   1 |
|  4 | www.site.com/sdsdadqwd12   | Some description here version 1 | 94b35433ecd64545db9c9129b877ea49 | Berlin | 52.51704 | 13.38886  | site    |   3 |
|  5 | www.page.com/dgdg2wg3      | Some description here version 2 | 764ed2b4f0d28e45332816c7beedb706 | Berlin | 52.51704 | 13.38886  | page    |   2 |
+----+----------------------------+---------------------------------+----------------------------------+--------+----------+-----------+---------+-----+
```

Now I would like to change my query to one that takes into account the order (priority) of services (sid) when removing.

2 example results with priority lists:

priority:

1. webpage
2. page
3. site
4. website

```
+----+--------------------------+---------------------------------+----------------------------------+--------+----------+-----------+---------+-----+
| id |           url            |           description           |         description_hash         |  city  | latitude | longitude | service | sid |
+----+--------------------------+---------------------------------+----------------------------------+--------+----------+-----------+---------+-----+
|  2 | www.page.com/gfdg3df2f2  | Some description here version 1 | 94b35433ecd64545db9c9129b877ea49 | Paris  | 48.85670 | 2.35146   | page    |   2 |
|  4 | www.site.com/sdsdadqwd12 | Some description here version 1 | 94b35433ecd64545db9c9129b877ea49 | Berlin | 52.51704 | 13.38886  | site    |   3 |
|  6 | www.webpage.com/8f8fj2h  | Some description here version 2 | 764ed2b4f0d28e45332816c7beedb706 | Berlin | 52.51704 | 13.38886  | webpage |   4 |
+----+--------------------------+---------------------------------+----------------------------------+--------+----------+-----------+---------+-----+
```

priority:

1. site
2. page
3. website
4. webpage

```
+----+--------------------------+---------------------------------+----------------------------------+--------+----------+-----------+---------+-----+
| id |           url            |           description           |         description_hash         |  city  | latitude | longitude | service | sid |
+----+--------------------------+---------------------------------+----------------------------------+--------+----------+-----------+---------+-----+
|  3 | www.site.com/sdjbhsjhd17 | Some description here version 1 | 94b35433ecd64545db9c9129b877ea49 | Paris  | 48.85670 | 2.35146   | site    |   3 |
|  4 | www.site.com/sdsdadqwd12 | Some description here version 1 | 94b35433ecd64545db9c9129b877ea49 | Berlin | 52.51704 | 13.38886  | site    |   3 |
|  5 | www.page.com/dgdg2wg3    | Some description here version 2 | 764ed2b4f0d28e45332816c7beedb706 | Berlin | 52.51704 | 13.38886  | page    |   2 |
+----+--------------------------+---------------------------------+----------------------------------+--------+----------+-----------+---------+-----+
```

General:

- I using postgresql
- I using md5 hashes because descriptions are very long and it takes too much time
- I want execute this query everyday on 1M rows

Somebody have any idea? I thinking about this all day and I have problem. I think about custom ordering rows against order by description_hash.

EDIT:

What's with the priority?

The current query deletes duplicate records RANDOM, that is, based on the ctid  so I have no control over which records are deleted.

My problem is that I would like to have control over it and be able to define it through a list of priorities, ranging from the most important sites to the least important.

The logic of the deletion should be as follows - when you hit a duplicate, verify what sites they come from and leave the one that is in the priority list at the highest.

SQL for testing:

```
create table my_table_data(
id int,
    url text,
    description text,
    description_hash text,
    city text,
    latitude double precision,
    longitude double precision,
    service text,
    sid int
);

insert into my_table_data(id, url, description, description_hash, city, latitude, longitude, service, sid) 
values(1, 'www.website.com/sdadsd12d1', 'Some description here version 1',  '94b35433ecd64545db9c9129b877ea49', 'Paris',    48.85670,   2.35146,    'website',  1);

insert into my_table_data(id, url, description, description_hash, city, latitude, longitude, service, sid) 
values(2, 'www.page.com/gfdg3df2f2',    'Some description here version 1',  '94b35433ecd64545db9c9129b877ea49', 'Paris',    48.85670,   2.35146,    'page', 2);

insert into my_table_data(id, url, description, description_hash, city, latitude, longitude, service, sid) 
values(3, 'www.site.com/sdjbhsjhd17',   'Some description here version 1',  '94b35433ecd64545db9c9129b877ea49', 'Paris',    48.85670,   2.35146,    'site', 3);

insert into my_table_data(id, url, description, description_hash, city, latitude, longitude, service, sid) 
values(4, 'www.site.com/sdsdadqwd12',   'Some description here version 1',  '94b35433ecd64545db9c9129b877ea49', 'Berlin',   52.51704,   13.38886,   'site', 3);

insert into my_table_data(id, url, description, description_hash, city, latitude, longitude, service, sid) 
values(5, 'www.page.com/dgdg2wg3',  'Some description here version 2',  '764ed2b4f0d28e45332816c7beedb706', 'Berlin',   52.51704,   13.38886,   'page', 2);

insert into my_table_data(id, url, description, description_hash, city, latitude, longitude, service, sid) 
values(6, 'www.webpage.com/8f8fj2h',    'Some description here version 2',  '764ed2b4f0d28e45332816c7beedb706', 'Berlin',   52.51704,   13.38886,   'webpage',  4);
```

Comment: Sample data in a *readable*, *text* format would help.  So would an explanation of the prioritization you want.  Nothing in your sample data is called `priority`, so you description is not clear.

Comment: Priorty list are on example .jpg results. I added on top of each other.

Comment: **Do NOT post images**. See [Why not upload images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). While the reference "code/errors"  it applies equally to sample data and results. See [here](https://senseful.github.io/text-table/) for creating formatted text. Then copy/paste the results into your question between lines containing only ```.

Comment: Your adding the "priority list" to your images does not hep. You did not explain what that are nor they are derived. I am sure you filly understand what it is but only you understand it.  A list of 4 items no matter how rearranged is still just a list of items.

Comment: Sorry guys for mistakes. I add priority description, whats going on, delete images and add sql for testing. I hope now its clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how to answer this other than generically, but let me try that.

From my best guess, a "duplicate" by your definition is the same description (or description hash) at the same location (lat/long or city).

If that is the case, then in order to delete those records and give preference to certain of them by defined, sortable conditions should be possible using the `row_number` analytic function.

For example, this query would give preference to the lowest "sid," where anything with row number = 1 would be retained and everything else removed.  If you wanted something other than sid or secondary/tertiary conditions, those would just be added to the "order by:"

```
select
  id, url, description, description_hash, city, latitude, longitude, service, sid,
  row_number() over (partition by description_hash, latitude, longitude order by sid) as rn
from my_table_data
```

In which case, deleting those records could be done in a simple step:

```
with dupes as (
  select
    id, row_number() over (partition by description_hash, latitude, longitude order by sid) as rn
  from my_table_data
)
delete from my_table_data m
where exists (
  select null
  from dupes d
  where
    d.id = m.id and
    d.rn > 1
)
```

Analytic functions and the semi-join are both very efficient, and 1M records should be very quick.

Hopefully this gives you the building blocks to do what you achieve your task.

Comment: Thanks for that tip @Hambone !!! I thought of similar logic, but didn't know the command "row_number () over partition by". I used your query + custom_sort function which sorts the data in the way indicated by me, not just ASC / DESC.And it's actually effective, it works much faster than my previous query. Custom sort function -> https://www.gab.lc/articles/order_by_custom_list/